# How to stop PyCharm from autocompleting HTML and Django template tags?

Tags: html, django, pycharm

When I'm writing Django templates with PyCharm it automatically closes them; this is reasonably helpful when I'm starting a new tag, but if my intention is to place some already existing content inside a different tag it tends to get a bit annoying, as I then have to delete or move the closing tag, e.g. I'll end up with something like this.

```
<div></div>Already existing text.
```

Is there any way of disabling this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [modify the smart keys](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/editor-smart-keys.html) functionality of the Editor by doing the following:

1. Go to `Settings --> Editor --> General --> Smart Keys`
2. Uncheck "insert closing tag on tag completion" under the "XML/HTML" section.

Answer (score 2):

Apprently, there is a way to achieve this already in PyCharm.

- Select the desired code fragment.
- Do one of the following:
- On the main menu, choose Code | Surround With
- Press `Ctrl+Alt+T`
- A pop-up window displays the list of enclosing statements according to the context.

Select the desired surround statement from the list. To do that, use the mouse cursor, up and down arrow keys, or a shortcut key displayed next to each element of the list.

Here is the [relevant documentation for `Wrapping`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html)

Here is the [documentation for `unwrapping`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/unwrapping-and-removing-statements.html)

EDIT:

The Shortcut for Tags is `Ctrl+Alt+J`

Here is the [relevant documentation for `tags`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/wrapping-a-tag-example-of-applying-surround-live-templates.html)

Comment: Does that actually allow you to wrap with HTML tags? I just tested it, and was only presented with Django template tags in the context menu that appeared. EDIT: According to the documentation you linked to, that seems to be the case (no HTML wrapping available).

Comment: this is by far a great feature and what you should do so that you can keep the feature active. HTML wrapping is availble, after ctrl+alt+T, press T again in an HTML document. @rnevius

Comment: Brilliant, @warath-coder. Definitely a great option (worked for me). Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: no @rnevius unfortunately i find the pyCharm documentation hard to navigate/read/find items... lots of googling and stackoverflow.  In this particular case, trial and error :)

Comment: So it looks like `ctrl + alt + j` is also an option.

Comment: the actual combination of keys to get the menu may depend on the short-cut layout/settings (appearance...>keymap) you choose.  I think mine is set for "Default for KDE'

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly the answer to the question I asked, but good to know that it's there. :)