# Automatically unindent closing HTML tags in PyCharm

Tags: html, pycharm

I have toggled every option that seems to make sense and have searched for an hour, but I can't find a solution.  I'm sure I'm just missing some magic word, and the solution is probably simple, but how do you make PyCharm automatically unindent closing HTML tags?

For example, if I type:

```
<div>
  Test
  </
```

PyCharm will automatically fill in the `div>`, but it will leave the indent hanging.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Part of the reason why I was particularly annoyed by this problem was that I was unable to backspace to the appropriate indent level before typing the closing tag, so to put the tag on the correct level, I had to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or press <kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823564/4830797) that pointed me to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys`, where I set `Backspace -> Unindent` to `To nearest indent position`, instead of `To proper indent position`, which dramatically reduced the annoyance level of the original issue.

I'll leave this open, as automatically unindenting closing tags (or automatically setting them to the "proper indent position") would still be the most ideal solution.

Comment: +1 I would also very much like this feature (similar to "Reformat block on typing '}'" for other languages)

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm automatically adds the closing tag when you type the starting tag. So when i type `<div>` there will be `</div>` directly added.

Comment: Right, but for a variety of reasons you may not type the opening tag, which is why it supports filling in the rest of the closing tag when you type `</`.

Comment: If you do not write the opening tag how can you expect pycharm to know what tag it has to use? If you have something like this in your example it would have added the closing tag before. Though I do not know why you have a problem to use that one second to write the closing tag it will not fasten your coding.

Comment: No, it _already_ finishes the closing tag.  All I want is for it to automatically deindent the line.  Many editors do this, and I have no doubt this one will, as well.